# How to select and set multiple textboxes text in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please I have my Jquery code that I want to do few things since. I have a form with a bunch of textboxes. I want to validate each textbox to allow numbers only. To also display error where not number.

```
 var validateForm = function(frm){
        var isValid = true;
        resetError();

        $(":text").each(function(variable){
            console.log("The variable is" , variable);
            if(!isNormalInteger(variable.val))
            {
                $("#error"+variable.id).text("Please enter an integer value");
                isValid = false;
            }
        });

        if(!isValid)
            return false;

    };
```

The above fails. When I print the variable on my console I was getting  numbers 0 - 9. My textboxes where empty yet, it returns numbers. I tried `variable.val()` still fails and return numbers. I modified my select to

```
$("input[type=text]", frm).each();
```

Where my form is my form selected by id. It also failed. Below is the example of my html label and textbox. I have about ten of them

```
<div class="grid-grid-8">
  <input class=" text" id="id" name="name" type="text">
    <br>
     <p class="hint">Once this limit is reached, you may no longer deposit.</p>
    <p class="errorfield" id="errorMAXCASHBAL"></p>
```

Please how do I select them properly? Moreover, my reset function above also returns incrementing integers for value. The p property is of class errorField and I want to set the text property. Please how do I achieve this? Previously I tried the class name only `$(.errorField)`. It also failed. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var resetError = function(){
        //reset error to empty
        $("p errorfield").each(function(value){
            console.log("the val", value);
            //value.text() = '';
        });
    };

//filter non integer/numbers 
function isNormalInteger(str) {
        return /^\+?\d+$/.test(str);
    }
```

Comment: Could you please add a jsFiddler to test it out?

Comment: What does "isNormalInteger" do?

Comment: @mplugjan It filters the text to ensure only intergers or numbers are keyed in by the user. I updated my code sir you can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `.each` wrong because the first parameter is the index and the second is the element. Check the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
Moreover, the correct selector for the resetError is: `p.errorfield`

So, you should modify your code to look something like this:

```
var resetError = function(){
    $("p.errorfield").each(function (idx, element) {
        $(element).text("");
    });
};
```

With this, I believe you can fix the upper function as well. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is your selectors in javascript. And as laszlokiss88 stated wrong usage of `.each()` function.

Here is a working example of your code: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wr20z97s/) in this example all `.each()` functions use `$(this)` selector inside instead of index and value